How do you count the number of employees of a company for the purposes of the 10-K
Please consider the following hypothetical situation: A public company is preparing its annual report known as the 10-K. The company has 10,000 employees on its payroll. In addition, it has two joint ventures with two different companies. In one of the joint ventures, it owns 20%. In the other joint venture it owns 50%. Each joint venture has 1000 employees. How many employees should the company report having on its 10-K?
Also, if they get it wrong, will anybody care?

A company would disclose the number of employees in the entity reported upon and would also report the percentage of ownership that it has in the other entities, which would file their own reports.
If they get it wrong, it could potentially give rise to a securities fraud lawsuit for violating the '34 Securities Exchange Act by making a false statement in an SEC report. But the lawsuit would only be allowed the  the error is material and causes harm.
The most likely way that it might be material and cause harm is that when combined with its payroll expenses in its financial statements, including too many employees would create a false impression that the company paid each employee less than it actually did, which in turn might suggest the management is able to limit pay more than competitors do, or that the company has an inferior quality workforce because it underpays its employees relative to market rate, suggesting that the company is weaker financially than it really is.

So if I understand your answer, in the case given in the post you would report just 10,000. Is that right?

@Bob That's right. They're just investors in the other companies -- the own shares of stock. That doesn't make empoyees of the other companies their employees in any way.
